# DATETIME function not found when used in TFDTable.Filter expression

Tags: sqlite, delphi, firedac

I'm using FireDAC with SQLite driver. (Delphi Tokyo 10.2.3)

Using `DATETIME` in a query expression works fine:

```
  with Query1 do
  begin
    Close;
    SQL.Text := 'select DATETIME(start_time) from times where ' +
      'DATETIME(start_time) >= DATETIME("2019-02-01 00:00:00")';
    Open;
    ....
  end;
```

However, if I try to assign a similar expression to TFDTable.Filter:

```
tblTimes.Filter := 'DATETIME(start_time) >= DATETIME("2019-02-01 00:00:00")';
tblTimes.Filtered := True;
```

It results in this error:

`[FireDAC][Stan][Eval]-100. Column or function [DATETIME] is not found. Hint: if the name is a function name, then add FireDAC.Stan.ExprFuncs to uses clause`

Note: FireDAC.Stan.ExprFuncs is already in uses clause

What is wrong? Can such an expression be used in Filter clause (it worked fine for me using aducom components in D7)?

Comment: Filtering for queries in most cases is done locally in Delphi code and not in the database engine. If the limited filtering it supports is not enough you can use  OnFilterRecord to do the filtering in your own code. ref: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Filtering_Records_(FireDAC)

Comment: DATETIME() is SQLite function so it can be used in query sql. In FD Dataset.Filter can be used only FD macro functions, DATETIME() is not build-in macro function.

Comment: @Branko there are exceptions - for example for a TFDTable in live data window mode the filter expression will be passed to the database engine in the WHERE clause (as mentioned near the bottom of the article I linked to above.)

Comment: @Brian: Thanks for the info. If you move to answer I will accept it.

Comment: To use the LDW it must be a really good reason and don't use LDW if you are not familiar with all the restrictions and recommendations for LDW. In general, avoid using FDTable, instead use FDQuery.

Comment: @Branko: What is LDW?

Comment: @RaelB:  live data window

Comment: Sure, as mentioned in the question, this worked fine in a legacy application using Aducom Components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
tblTimes.Filter := 'start_time >= {dt 2019-02-01 00:00:00}';
tblTimes.Filtered := True;
```

and please read this:
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Preprocessing_Command_Text_(FireDAC)

Comment: Not sure how this will help me. I need to apply a function to `start_time` to obtain the desired result.

Comment: I assume that `start_time` is the column in TDataSet. What datatype is `start_time` column?

Comment: It is declared as DATETIME

Comment: OK, so my answer is exactly what you need. And no, you do not have to use any function.
For FireDAC, the value labeled "{dt <value>}" is treated as the DateTime value.
Just try and share your results :)

Comment: Ok. I will try and test it sometime. I have already converted app based on Brian's comments...

Comment: Filtering by the `OnFilterRecord` event is not necessary because filtering in FireDAC has really great possibilities. In addition, it requires an event handler instead of passing the filter expression to `DataSet.Filter`

Comment: Thanks. It works great. It is alot faster than using OnFilterRecord.